# parts of page only load on refresh command

Tags: firefox, browser

I have an occasional issue with pages, that I don't know how to recreate, since they seldom seem to do it for more than a few days. I also haven't seen a pattern for what sites do it. I would like to fix it, but I'm more interested in what causes it. Is it a connection issue? Is it the site? Is it a bug shared by multiple browsers?

WHAT HAPPENS

The page partially loads, and stalls. I refresh the page, and additional parts of the page INSTANTLY appear but only briefly, as they disappear again when it reloads the page. I can get the second part to stay if I stop the page from reloading, though I usually have to do so within a 1/4 second after telling it to reload.

DETAILS

I've not taken notes on it before, but it's happening now, and I'm using Firefox. It works fine with Chrome. Edge and IE do similar to FF, except they never display the second part at all, even between reloads, and the loading circle goes away after a short while. At least they're honest, I suppose O_o I think I could go watch a movie, and FF would still be "loading"

WHAT I'VE TRIED

I've also tried rebooting, power cycling the WiFi, and using FF in safe mode. I THINK the first time with safe mode, it loaded the second part on its own, but not sure, and otherwise behaves exactly the same as normal mode.

I have somewhat recently reinstalled FF, for unrelated reasons that also still linger. I wiped the old profile, but imported the bookmarks from it, and possibly another thing or two, but I can't remember what they were. I do remember that it wasn't the addons, I manually went and found the

Due to the instantaneous nature of its appearance, it's as if the second part of the page is loaded, but not displayed.

I've had this happen, if only occasionally, for years, and the behavior baffles me.

Comment: Open up the developer tools (ctrl-shift-I) and look at the errors tab and/or the network monitor.  If there are javascript or other errors it might help explain the problem.

Comment: I get a 404 from a .css file, and in case it matters, a crapload of 304 (not modified)...I guess I can kinda see how a missing .css file would prevent something from displaying at all, but could it cause it to only display on page reload? Anyway, emailing my school about it too, thanks.